# Test Angular data binding with cypress

Tags: angular, cypress, integration-testing

I've just started testing my Angular App and I need to check if some bound attributes contain what I want.
Let's say I want to check this: 
`<mat-table data-testid="table" [attr_t]="mydata">`.
`cy.byTestId('table').invoke('attr','attr_t').should('eq', mydata)` doesn't work for data bound attributes.

Comment: What is the DOM at runtime? The documents indicate you should have `<table attr_t="whatever mydata variable contained">`. Take a look in devtools to see what Angular has delivered to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Now I have found a solution:

To the bound attributes "ng-reflect-" is added at the beginning and rewritten to kebab-case.

```
test = 'iconName';

<global-icon [icon]="test"> </global-icon>

cy.get('global-icon').invoke('attr', 'ng-reflect-icon').should('equal', 'iconName');
```

or

```
test = 'top';

<global-icon [ownPosition]="test"> </global-icon>

cy.get('global-icon').invoke('attr', 'ng-reflect-own-position').should('equal', 'top');
```

I hope this helps.